# Add columns content if the header is selected as 1 or 0

Tags: google-sheets

Trying to add across horizontally - if the column header is selected as being `1` - then the values of the column are to be added to the adjacent one that has `1` as a header.

Ff the column header is selected as `0` - then those contents won't be added.

I am trying to use the column headers like "on" and "off": `1` = on and `0` = off

This is a marks sheet used by teachers - and sometimes they don't want to add the marks - if the students did badly in it.

So I want them to have the flexibility of just using a drop down to switch on and off the column.

Comment: I hope this is just an example spreadsheet, and not the actual students' marks?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `FILTER` function for this.

Let's say you have values of `1` or `0`, in row 2, to indicate if the column is enabled.

To sum row 7 (column `A` through `I`), you would write `=SUM(FILTER(A7:I7; A$2:I$2 = 1))`

You could also use other values than `1` and `0`, let's say `TRUE` or `FALSE`:
`=SUM(FILTER(A7:I7; A$2:I$2 = TRUE))`